# Setting session after form completion

Tags: php, session, perch

I am adding in a form with just 2 radio buttons using Perch CMS and trying to stop it from having the option of resubmitting the form after it has been submitted once during a session by finding the success code of `<!--@@^^res@@^^-->`

I have the session start above all other code and also above my  but cannot get it to work properly.

My code is as follows which in my head says if the session is equal to submitted then the success code is there and so will not show the content however if there is not session set then the success code is not there and therefore requires the content to be displayed. Once the form is submitted and the success code is output, a session of submitted is then created...

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['survey']) == 'submitted')
echo (strpos($content,'<!--@@^^res@@^^-->')!=false);
 else {
        $content = perch_content('Survey',true);
    echo str_replace('<!--@@^^res@@^^-->','',$content);

    if (strpos($content,'<!--@@^^res@@^^-->')!=true) {
        $_SESSION['survey'] = 'submitted'; 
    };
 };
    ?>
```

I noticed that this works upon load as in I get the form there but when I change page it disappears as well as after filling out the form.

tried Googling this but cannot get my head round where I am going wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I take it that `session_start();` is loaded somewhere? If it isn't, add it. It's required when using sessions.

Comment: session_start is within my global header file.

Comment: You shouldn't be embedding "magic codes" in your html. Nothing stops a malicious user from capturing/repeating that code elsewhere where it shouldn't be. You're using sessions - store the success code there, where it's out of reach of everyone but your code. And note that your strpos call will fail if the code is at the start of the string. strpos at that point is 0, which tests as false. YOu should be using strict equality testing `!== false`, which won't get fooled by that.

Comment: Does the same apply to the !==true as well?

Comment: `strpos` _never_ returns `true`, so checking for that – or even it’s negation – is quite nonsensical.

Comment: What would your suggestion be in replacement to that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of CBroe advising me that `strpos` can never return true I have done a bit more messing around and reading up on `strpos` and found the following code works...

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['survey']) == 'submitted')
echo (strpos($content,'<!--@@^^res@@^^-->')!=true);
 else {
        $content = perch_content('Survey',true);
    echo str_replace('<!--@@^^res@@^^-->','',$content);

    if (strpos($content,'<!--@@^^res@@^^-->')!==false) {
        $_SESSION['survey'] = 'submitted'; 
    };
 };
    ?>
```

All left to do now is to stop `1` being displayed in the area whilst the session is active.